# SQL Server 2008 R2 view assistance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have several views and tables which I am trying to connect in one view to create a website GUI for several users (and myself) to use.  It is basically an inventory system which is linking together purchase information which has been dumped into a SQL table + internal asset tag + user accessing.  Tables are similar to:

- Assets - Serial Number, ID
- UserAudit - UserName, AssetsID, OfficeID, date/time
- Office - location
- Orders - Serial Number, detail

Several of the assets are Computers and the UserAudit is populated by a logon script which records the users name, computers name, and date/time.  I am trying to create a view which links all of the information based upon Assets list regardless of if they related tables have matching data.  For the UserAudit side I just want to display the most recent record (date field Desc).

The place I am running into an issue is grabbing just the top record from the UserAudit based upon the ComputerName while still returning all of the columns from the others.  I tried creating a separate view for the UserAudit with showing 'Top 1' - this however limited the main view to only 1 result as well if I use an "inner Join" and doesn't display anything from the UserAUdit when using any OUTER join.

I did some research in which a Cross Apply looks like it might be relevant, however I have not used this before and attempts have not worked well.  The view currently looks like:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT 
    dbo.AssetType.AssetType, dbo.AssetTagInventory.ID, dbo.AssetTagInventory.AssetDetail, 
    dbo.AssetTagInventory.Name, dbo.AssetTagInventory.Serial, dbo.AssetTagInventory.UserID, 
    dbo.AssetTagInventory.Age, dbo.AssetTagInventory.Notes, 
    dbo.vewOffices.Name AS OfficeName, 
    dbo.AssetTagPurchases.PurchaseDate, dbo.AssetTagPurchases.ProductDescription AS Model, 
    dbo.AssetTagPurchases.ID AS AECOrderNumber, 
    dbo.AssetTagPurchases.Vendor, dbo.AssetTagPurchases.QuotedPrice, 
    dbo.AssetTagPurchases.InvoicedPrice, dbo.AssetTagPurchases.InvoiceNum, 
    dbo.AssetTagPurchases.VendorOrderNumber, dbo.vewLogonAudit.Username, 
    dbo.vewLogonAudit.LoginTime
FROM  
    dbo.AssetTagInventory 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.vewLogonAudit ON dbo.AssetTagInventory.Name = dbo.vewLogonAudit.ComputerName 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AssetType ON dbo.AssetTagInventory.AssetTypeID = dbo.AssetType.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.vewOffices ON dbo.AssetTagInventory.OfficeID = dbo.vewOffices.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.AssetTagPurchases ON dbo.AssetTagInventory.Serial = dbo.AssetTagPurchases.Serial
```

Comment: Use a nested subquery to select only the top 1 UserAudit record and join to that. Additionally, writing your join keywords at the end of the line, rather than the start, makes it really obnoxious to read your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `OUTER APPLY`.  It should be just what you need here.
It should work with something like  (among/after the other joins):

```
OUTER APPLY
    (   SELECT TOP 1 <columns>
        FROM dbo.UserAudit 
        WHERE     dbo.AssetTagInventory.<??> = dbo.UserAudit.<??>
        ORDER BY <...>
    ) T_UserAudit
```

*EDIT*

Try using a unique alias after the closing brackets:

```
OUTER APPLY(...) TLA
```

And then in the Select-Part, use the alias without `dbo.`

```
SELECT .., ... , TLA.UserName
```

Maybe that's the only little bit to get it going.

Comment: I have tried multiple variations and keep failing.  If I declare the columns in the first Select I get a "multi-part identifier" error, if I don't declare them in the initial select it parses out correctly but doesn't display any of the data.  Below is one of the examples that I have tried:

Comment: SELECT dbo.vewOffices.Name AS OfficeName, [dbo].[vewLogonAudit].[Username], dbo.AssetTagInventory.ID
FROM  dbo.AssetTagInventory INNER JOIN
               dbo.vewOffices ON dbo.AssetTagInventory.OfficeID = dbo.vewOffices.ID
OUTER APPLY
    (   SELECT TOP 1 [dbo].[vewLogonAudit].[Username]
        FROM dbo.vewLogonAudit 
        WHERE     [dbo].[AssetTagInventory].[name] = [dbo].[vewLogonAudit].[ComputerName]
    ) vewLogonAudit

Comment: Hi, I have made an edit to my answer. (You can best edit your original question to add new code, it doesn't work well in a comment.)

Comment: It is working!  My only question/issue now is the speed, the query runs quite slowly.  Without that UserAudit it takes 0:00, with it the query takes 1:26.  I'm assuming the reason is because it is running the search each time for every record.  I tried limiting it a bit by only have it search the last 6 months of records (and will probably reduce that more), but is there any other way to increase this?  I am checking to see if the original table it is referencing is indexed or not and will report back on that.

Comment: Okay - ignore that apparently the person who built the original Audit table never indexed it.  Added in some indexes and that is down to 0:07.